# Bootstrap is not working on this component

Tags: html, angular, angular-bootstrap

The bootstrap is applied on the search button and the shopping cart icon but not the rest. The bootstrap does not work on the nav bar. Not sure if its just a typo problem but I got it to work earlier and then it crashed

```
<div class="myclass">
  <nav id="myid" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #171d20; height: 60px">
    <form id="page" class="form-inline">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="hello" routerLink="Userlogin/home" href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Departments </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">department 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">department 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">department 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li (click)="onLogin()" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
          <a routerLink="/Userlogin" class="hello" href="#">Login & Signup</a>
        </li>

        <li><a routerLink="/profile" class="hello" href="#">Profile</a></li>

        <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{ username }}
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a routerLink="/Userlogin/orders" href="#2">Orders</a></li>
            <li><a (click)="onLogout()">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a routerLink="Userlogin/cart" class="hello" href="#"> Cart</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/login" class="hello" href="#">Admin</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div>
        <a style="margin-left: 180px; margin-top: 3px; font-size: medium" class="navbar-brand">Shop24X7</a>
      </div>

      <input [(ngModel)]="search" name="search" size="40" style="margin-top: 11px" class="form-control mr-sm-2"
        type="search" placeholder="Search for product" aria-label="search" />
      <button (click)="onSearch()" style="margin-top: 11px" class="btn btn-info" type="submit">
        <a href="Userlogin/search"> Search </a>
      </button>

      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="cart" class="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-1">
        <img routerLink="cart" src="https://img.icons8.com/cute-clipart/64/000000/food-cart.png" />
      </a>
    </form>
  </nav>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: What sort of error shows up on the console? and what do you see on the screen?

Comment: there's no error shown in the console. the application works fine except bootstrap is not applied everywhere. just partially in each component I have. I have installed bootstrap and applied it into my angular.json file as well. Another way I tried is pasting this @import url("bootstrap.min.css"); into styles.css but it gives me an error as It cannot find this file in the node_modules

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by 'working partially in each component'. Also please share your component's style sheet file, angular.json and any other relevant code snippet.